# Reset a unique_ptr that references itself from its deleter

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, unique-ptr

I have a Main class that has a `unique_ptr<Watcher>` field that starts a thread which calls a member function from Main when it has events. `~Main()` sets the watcher `unique_ptr` to `nullptr` before calling `~Watcher()`, which means its thread can still call `main.event()` which references watcher (a `nullptr`).

Can I stop the watcher thread before the `unique_ptr` gets reset, and avoid the `nullptr` dereference?

```
struct Main {
    struct Watcher {
        Watcher(Main &main)
            : main(main)
            , th(std::thread(&Watcher::func, this))
        { }
        
        void func() { while (!stop) main.event(); }        
        
        int eventInfo() { return 0; }
        
        ~Watcher()
        {
            stop = true;
            th.join();
        }
        
        Main &main;
        std::thread th;
        bool stop{};
    };

    Main()
        : watcher(std::make_unique<Watcher>(*this))
    { }

    void event() { std::cout << watcher->eventInfo() << "\n"; }
    
    std::unique_ptr<Watcher> watcher;
};
```

Comment: Why not just simply put `watcher->stop = true;` in `Main`'s destructor?

Comment: @Genjutsu that won't work. First of all, you change and read `stop` in two different threads, this is a bad idea without atomic or mutex, or another way of synchronization. And lets assume for a moment that it won't be a problem then you still could have the situation that the thread reads `stop` as `false` then `watcher->stop = true;` and the destruction is done, and after that, the thread continues with its call to `main.event()`.

Comment: Well you can move `stop = true; th.join();` into separate method and make `stop` atomic.

Comment: Besides an already-mentioned data race on `stop`, you have a data race on `watcher`. For all you know, the worker thread is dereferencing `watcher` inside `event()` at the exact moment that `~Main` does `watcher = nullptr;`. Instead of tearing down the thread in destructor, give `Watcher` an explicit `Stop` method that would signal `stop` and join the thread. `Main` would then call it before destroying `Watcher`